# Is there a way to insert an image via URL in CKEditor 5?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ckeditor

I'm currently learning Vue.js & Node.js, and I can't find out a way to insert images with URL, not upload them to the server. I'm using CKEditor 5's official package for Vue, here's my code:

```html
<template>
  <v-container>
    <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'

export default {
  name: 'NewPost',

  data: function () {
    return {
      editor: ClassicEditor,
      editorData: '',
      editorConfig: {}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!